# Add modifier to all instances of view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to use my theme color on all instances of `Toggle()`, is there a way to do this with an extension?

```
extension Toggle {
    func content() -> some View {
        self.tint(.red)
    }
}
```

The above is not working, is there something else I should call on the extension to modify all instances of `Toggle`?

Comment: The easiest way is to create your own MyToggle() struct that has its custom appearance.

Comment: Purpose of the Extensions is to extend the behaviour of the class/struct. If you want  to modify all instances, you should apply the changes in the initialiser of Toggle view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what [`.toggleStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/togglestyle) is designed for. Create your own custom ToggleStyle:

```
struct MyToggleStyle: ToggleStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        // This just extends the default Toggle appearance, but you can return
        // any View you like here. It doesn't have to call `Toggle` first.
        Toggle(configuration)
            .tint(.red) // Along with whatever other styles you like
    }
}

extension ToggleStyle where Self == MyToggleStyle {
    static var myToggleStyle: MyToggleStyle { .init() }
}
```

Then in your top-level ContentView, add the modifier:

```
.toggleStyle(.myToggleStyle)
```

Your style will be applied to all Toggles inside of your ContentView.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to make a [custom view](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/declaring-a-custom-view) with [`@ViewBuilder`](https://www.raywenderlich.com/30070603-viewbuilder-tutorial-creating-reusable-swiftui-views#toc-anchor-007).

```swift
struct CustomToggle<Content: View>: View {
    var isOn: Binding<Bool>
    var label: Content

    var body: some View {
        Toggle(isOn: isOn) { label }
            .tint(.red)
    }
    
    init(isOn: Binding<Bool>, @ViewBuilder label: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.isOn = isOn
        self.label = label()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a modifier to apply to an instance of `Toggle()`, can do that with the help of `ViewModifiers`.

i.e: First create a ViewModifier:

```
struct TintColorModifier: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .tint(.red)
    }
}
```

---

```
extension Toggle {
    func tintStyle() -> some View {
        modifier(TintColorModifier())
    }
}
```

Now you can use the extension this way:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Toggle()
            .tintStyle() // <-- Here
    }
}
```